# Overload python ternary operator

Tags: python, operator-overloading, ternary-operator

Is it possible to overload the ternary operator in python? Basically what I want is something like:

```
class A(object):
    def __ternary__(self, a, c):
        return a + c

a = A()
print "asdf" if a else "fdsa" # prints "asdffdsa"
```

I'm trying to implement a symbolic package and basically want something that can do things like:

```
sym = Symbol("s")
result = 1 if sym < 3 else 10
print result.evaluate(sym=2) # prints 1
print result.evaluate(sym=4) # prints 10
```

**Edit**: Let me put out a bit more complex example to show how this could be layered upon.

```
sym = Symbol("s")
result = 1 if sym < 3 else 10
...
something_else = (result+1)*3.5
...
my_other_thing = sqrt(something_else)

print my_other_thing.evaluate(sym=2) # prints sqrt(7) or rather the decimal equivalent
```

The point is, I don't need to just be able to late evaluate the one ternary operator, I need to take the result and do other symbolic stuff with that before finally evaluating. Furthermore, my code can do partial evaluations where I give it a few bindings and it returns another symbolic expression if it can't evaluate the full expression.

My backup plan is just to directly use the ternary class taking 3 expressions objects that I would need to make anyway. I was just trying to hide the generation of this class with an operator overload. Basically:

```
a = TernaryOperator(a,b,c)
# vs
b = a if b else c
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to overload the comparison operators (and convert-to-bool operator; don't know what the proper Python term is) instead?

Comment: I think you have the comparison backwards on your example - should be `if sym < 3`

Comment: @HughBothwell Good call

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset How would you implement what I'm trying to do then? If I understand correct, what you're suggesting would get evaluated at the `result=...` line instead of the print lines.

Comment: Use lambda functions - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. look at the [`sympy` module](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html); it already does this
2. for simple comparison, write `A.__eq__` and `A.__lt__` methods and use the [total_ordering class decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering); this should be sufficient for comparing two `A`s or an `A` and a constant
3. write it as a lambda,

   ```
   result = lambda sym: 1 if sym < 3 else 10
   print(result(2))    # => 1
   print(result(4))    # => 10
   ```

Comment: Your lambda operates on the integers 2 and 4.

Comment: Yes, it does; per his example, `result.evaluate(sym=2)`, this may be sufficient for his needs.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the comparison operators instead (something you probably needed to do anyway):

```
class A(object):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value() < other.value() # Replace with your own implementation of <
```

Then, use lambda functions to achieve the delayed evaluation you desire:

```
sym = Symbol("s")
result = lambda s: 1 if s < 3 else 10
sym.set(2)
print result(sym) # prints 1
sym.set(4)
print result(sym) # prints 10
```

(I don't think you can overload the assignment operator, as it doesn't actually perform an operation on any *object*, but rather on a *variable*.)

Comment: it's actually the ternary operator I was hoping to overload (not the assignment operator) but I have a feeling that you just can't overload it, which is too bad